# datatable custom column filter work in codepen example but not in html page

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am creating a table using datatables plugin, the custom column filtering is work perfectly in my codepen but not in my actual html page.

you may find the working codepen code in the comment.

The custom filter in my actual html page was render as duplicated header without the input box.

[image]

Comment: codepen: https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/BqwYzg

Comment: Change html to append() $(this).append( '<input type="text" placeholder=""/>' ); uncomment this line 
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

Comment: Hi @JesseJay, i don't understand this part: Change html to append() $(this).append( '<input type="text" placeholder=""/>' ); can you explain more?

Comment: html() method if its matches more than one element, only the first match will be returned try using append() inserts the content as the last child of each element maybe it will work it your local machine.

Comment: i am still seeing the same problem.  not input box was render.

Comment: looks like this is my mistake, i use td for my header instead of th.  once i change them to th the page is rendered correctly.